# python 3.8 and pip gives this error[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Tags: python-3.8

$ pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/00/86/63b1967d59c3424992f0f822b012bcf24d8d013f8d65b40db20fae01be70/pygame-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Answer (score 0):

**Change** your timezone with:

```
timedatectl set-timezone yourtimezone/name
```

To get the list of timezones `timedatectl list-timezones`

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall all stuff of python 1st. Then delete that file from pc. Then uninstall python interpreter and download python form its official page again and install it and also install python interpreter again then

**Check it in your cmd or powershell is it running perfectly or not.**
It will definitely run.

I am getting the same problem but it was resolved now.